# Shopify API Request Limit, Multiple stores?

Tags: shopify

If I may ask, I was wondering how the API request limit handles multiple store calls?

**Scenario:**

We have one backend service "polling" a store with one core request and 'x' number of requests for images by productId for each item in "LineItems" (I doubt this will be an extraordinary figure) every 5 seconds, but I'm curious to know if we had Five stores and Five background service polling respective stores, would this total to the request limit? I.E how is this tracked, by IP?

I'm hoping that it's on a per store basis thus other stores have there own "Bucket". I have read through "Some" documentation but not sure that info is giving the knowledge I require.

There a lot of older posts and articles, all with conflicting info.

I fully appreciate this is not a programming issue per-say but was hoping this was the place for such a question. As ever, appreciate everyone's time.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All shops are provided with a two API calls per second limit, after you've hammered your bucket for 40 other calls. If you are polling a shop every 5 seconds, then you are in no danger of hitting any limits. Any one App can call N stores and this limit is per store, not per App.

Comment: Graciously answered, Thank you.